# What does the {HTTPS} variable actually represent?

Tags: iis, rewrite, isapi-rewrite

I am writing a rule with the *IIS Rewrite module* to detect if a URL request is formed `HTTP://` or `HTTPS://`

The documentation says "*HTTPS can be used to determine if a secure connection was used*".
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Accessing_URL_Parts_from_a_Rewrite_Rule

But it's possible that a valid HTTPS URL may not be secure (eg because of an invalid SSL certificate).
In which case would the `{HTTPS}` variable be true or false?

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a point of clarification: the {HTTPS} variable will evaluate to `on` or `off`, not `true` or `false`. The variable should evaluate to `on` if it is an https connection (even if the certificate is invalid).

Comment: That's good to know.  So in short - when the word 'secure' is used it shouldnt always be taken literally