# What happens after a rewrite rule is processed in IIS?

Tags: iis, rewrite, isapi-rewrite

I have a couple of rules set up for a site, made with the *IIS rewrite module.*

What happens after each rule is processed, does it stop processing rules after the first one is performed, or does it go on to process the next (in which case how can I prevent this) ?

Does the order of the rules matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module will continue to process rules by default, and the order does matter.  Enabling the `StopProcessing` flag will modify this behavior, but it does different things for different types of rules. Rewrite rules will stop being evaluated after a rule with this flag matches.  Redirect rules will not.

Comment: Redirect rules do not respect Stop Processing, they always stop