# Redirect www.* URLs in IIS

Tags: iis, rewrite

I need to find an easy and universal way of catching any `http://www.sub.example.com` URLs and redirecting them to `http://sub.example.com` (ie stripping out the www)

I'd prefer to implement this once for the server and not for each site, maybe using IIS Rewriter?

Comment: we need to know what version of iis you are using

Comment: @MichaelHenderson I actually have two servers one is IIS 7.5 the other is IIS 10.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to make a redirect rule in IIS URL Rewrite Module as follows:

**Match URL**
Requested URL: `Matches the Pattern`
Using: `Regex`
Pattern: `*` and `Ignore case`

**Conditions**
Logical grouping: `Match Any`
Input: `{HTTP_HOST}`
Type: Matches the Pattern
Pattern: `^(www\.)(.*)$`

**Server Variables**
Leave blank.

**Action**
Action type: `Redirect`
Redirect URL: `https://{C:2}{PATH_INFO}`
Append query string: `checked` Redirect type: `Permanent (301)`

Apply the rule and run IISReset.

Alternatively, after installing the module you could modify web.config as follows:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Strip www" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Regex" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*" negate="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input=""{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}{PATH_INFO}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This rule is meant to check any URL (*), find an instance of "www." (case insensitive by default) in {HTTP_HOST}, and then redirect to the second part of the canonical hostname {C:2} with the rest of path appended to the end {PATH_INFO}. This rule may fail you if there was a request for something like `http://bad.www.example.com/some/page.html` as it would return `https://www.example.com/some/page.html`, but it should work for most cases.

Comment: Thanks !  Needed a couple of tweaks to get it work, but it now works great.  (You specified "Wildcard" but then went on to use a Regex).  <rule name="Strip www from URL and retry" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" negate="false" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:2}{PATH_INFO}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

Comment: Whoops! cut and paste error from my previous post.  Thanks for the correction.