# Force https on all website except one on IIS

Tags: https, rewrite, iis-10, windows-server-2022

I followed this example ["Best way to redirect all HTTP to HTTPS in IIS"](https://serverfault.com/a/893804/59127) for redirecting to https and it worked great.

I just have one website that is the exception. It has a few non-https map references that prevent the site from loading correctly under https. For now, until the site is updated, I have to use http.

Am I correct in assuming I'll have to create a condition to do this in the current rule?

So, with that being said, can I exclude a domain while requiring all others to use https through one URL Rewrite rule?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change condition to doesn't match your excluded site:

[image]

or

2. Add another rule *before* existing - match your excluded site, action=none and stop processing:

[image]

Comment: tyvm for the info!